# 3.3V <-> 24V interface

Tags: interface, level-shifting, converter, beaglebone-black

I need to interface an ARM µC (BeagleBone Black) with a 24VDC system.
24VDC sensors and 24VDC actuators should be connected to the BeagleBone Black.

I am wondered how to do this.

I have found a dedicated circuit : the [iC-JX - 4x4 Bidirectional 24 V High-Side Driver with Load Diagnosis and μC Interface](http://www.ichaus.de/product/iC-JX) from ichaus  but maybe it have others solutions.

For the moment I don't know how many inputs and outputs that I need but I think that 8 inputs and 8 outputs should be sufficient.

Edit :

The input sensors should be :

- a magnetic scale position sensor [ASM PMIS3-50-50-50KHZ-HTL-Z0-2M-S](http://www.asm-sensor.com/asm/pdf/pro/pmis3_en.pdf)
- a proximity sensor for cylinder [Festo SME-8M](https://www.festo.com/cat/de_de/data/doc_engb/PDF/EN/SMX8_EN.PDF)
- 24VDC from NO/NC switches

Outputs should be :

- Solenoid coils (24VDC / ~100mA 300mA max)
- Relay (24VDC / 30mA) => Can be replaced with a 5VDC/140mW model

Comment: What sort of sensors are they? Sometimes a simple resistor divider will be fine possibly with a bit of extra protection. Also do you actually need high side drivers, sometimes low side is a bit more flexible because you'll also be able to work with 12V systems etc.

Comment: Sensors are buttons, cylinder sensor and linear incremental encoder

Comment: Not enough information - can you provide links for the buttons, cylinder sensor and incremental encoder. What devices are you trying to drive - links please.

Comment: I've added more information about devices.

Comment: I've also found some circuits like [Infineon BTS4880-R](http://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/automotive-ics/smart-high-and-low-side-switches/profet-tm-smart-high-side-switches/BTS4880-R/productType.html?productType=db3a304412fcb7bb011320570d261c41) and [VNQ500](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/sense_power/FM1965/SC1037/PF222735) for the output driver. Maybe a voltage divider is sufficient for the inputs ?

Comment: The output Magnetic scale position sensor itself is TTL/RS422 compatible. I think, any protection circuit may not be required for this sensor,

Comment: Not for this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you're talking about using the 'Bone in an industrial application, I'd probably suggest using optocouplers on your inputs. I'd probably use a bank of eight 4N35s. You could also find an optocoupler chip with multiple gates but the 4N35 is cheap and ubiquitous.

An optocoupler with open collector output (the most common type) would probably require a pull-up resistor on the output. The 'Bone may be able to activate some in-chip pull-up but resistors are cheap as air so you might as well have the certainty of an external pull-up (say, 4.7 kΩ).

The input of the optocoupler should be treated like and LED. At 24 V, you want to drive somewhere between 10 and 20 mA, so you'll want a 1.5 kΩ resistor in series with the input. Note that the power dissipation of this resistor will be P=V^2/R≈400 mW, so use a 1 W resistor.

To protect the input from reverse voltage transients, you will often see a diode placed in antiparallel with the optocoupler input.

For your output, it's hard to go past the classic ULN2803 relay driver. Again, it's cheap and ubiquitous. It'll drive your relays and solenoids. You may have to watch the power dissipation, though, if you're PWM switching the solenoids or have a lot of them.

Have a look at the schematics for this Arduino clone (disclaimer: I did the latest revision of this design) for an example circuit using optoisolated inputs and the ULN2803:
http://oceancontrols.com.au/KTA-223.html

Comment: Yes but the ULN2803 is a low side switch and it is less safe. Especially for industrial application.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, looking at the inputs and outputs you want to use, I think the 4x4 driver IC you suggested is overkill for the application.

For inputs, there is a variant of that magnetic position sensor with a TTL output which you should be able to interface directly. If I've understood what you mean about the 24V input switches, a simple resistor network should scale that down to 3.3V, preferably with something like a Zener diode in parallel to absorb any transients about 3.3V from the sensors.

For outputs, the BTS4880-R or VNQ500 will probably work or you might be able to do the same with discrete transistors, which could be cheaper/easier depending on your application/volume.

Answer (score 0):

TTL industrial controls quite often used the ULN or a TTL open collector buffer to pull down the base of a PNP transistor giving the 24V control. Over current protection can be covered with a common supply using the current limit on a 78xx regulator reverse is done with a diode.